SQL Server scalar variable holds only last value from table result instead of throwing an error
I have a source table that I think whose table stores only one distinct period. I'm assigning that period to an int variable like below.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tarih INT;
------------
SELECT @tarih = Dates
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           [Period] AS Dates
    FROM MySourceTable STG WITH(NOLOCK)
) a

But one day I noticed by chance that the table can return more than one value. In this situation, I would expect that SQL Server throws an error. Instead, it takes only last value from table set.
When I change the code like below, it throws an error just as I expect.
DECLARE @tarih INT;
------------
SELECT @tarih = 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           [Period]
    FROM MySourceTable STG WITH(NOLOCK)
) 


Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
an expression.

What is the difference between these two syntaxes? Shouldn't the first query also get an error? Do they work differently in the background?

Side note: With(NoLock) isn't a magic turbo button, it's a magic "get dirty reads" button.  For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's Bad Habits: Putting NOLOCK Everywhere

The second query is actually the same as using set instead of select because there is no from before the subquery. And therefor in the second only one value is allowed to return, whereas in the first query you actually retrieve a list of values and then ask for one value from that list

This behavior is documented in the Variables (Transact-SQL) page:

If a SELECT statement returns more than one row and the variable references a nonscalar expression, the variable is set to the value returned for the expression in the last row of the result set.

The rules for a subquery are different - a subquery can return multiple values if used with set operators such as in, exists, any etc', or with a table alias (as a part of the from or apply clause`.
When a subquery is used as an expression or after a scalar operator, it must return a single scalar value, as specified in the error message you've quoted in the question.
For more information, read the documentation on Subquery types.
